# Meaning and etymology of ūrīnor and ūrīna: "to dive" comes from "pee"?

Tags: etymology, meaning

Starting from a Bart Simpson prank call, I looked for "urinator" in Wiktionary, and suddenly found myself faced with [the Latin meaning of the word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urinator#Latin), that is, *ūrīnātor* meaning "diver". And I was like no, I can't believe that. And things got even more unbelievable when I clicked the link to *ūrīnōr*, and found it means "to dive" and comes from *ūrīna*, urine. What? No seriously, how exactly did this kind of pretty drastic meaning change come to be? Is *ūrīnōr* really from *ūrīna*? Did *ūrīna* mean "urine"? Can we go further back in the etymology of *ūrīnor* / *ūrīna*? Did *ūrīnor* ever mean "to urinate"?

(Latine repetam pro iis, qui Anglicam linguam non optime comprehendunt)

#### De significatione ac etymologia verborum "ūrīna" et "ūrīnor": "in aquam insilire" a verbo "mingere" venit?

Incipiens a Bartolomæi Simpson ludo telephonico quodam, in Wiktionarium quæsivi "urinator" (verbum Anglicum), et subito inveni [significationem Latinam huius verbi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urinator#Latin), id est, *ūrīnātor*, quod aliquem qui in aquam insilit significat (Anglice *diver*). Reactio mea fuit "Minime, hoc credere nequeo!". Et situatio etiam incredibilior facta est cum ligamen clickavi ad *ūrīnor*, et inveni id *in aquam insilire* (Anglice *dive*) significare, et ab *ūrīna* (liquidum quod mingentes expellimus) originem trahere. Quit? Serie, exacte quomodo potuit tam drasticum mutamentum significationis fieri? Verene *ūrīnor* ab *ūrīna* venit? Significatio verbi *ūrīna* quam supra scripsi verane est? Possumusne magis retro ire in etymologiam verborum *ūrīnor* et *ūrīna*? Verbumne *ūrīnor* umquam *mingere* significavit?

Comment: +1 for gorgeous Latin.

Comment: Thx @Joel. Being Italian helps a tiny bit, I guess :).

Comment: Btw I was lucky with _Bart_ which is an abbreviation for _Bartholomew_ hence _Bartholomæus_, but can you think of any sensible way to latinize _Simpson_?

Comment: de Vaan mentions two hypotheses: 1. The original meaning might have been "water" cf. urinari 'dive' 2. The original meaning might have been urine, because divers produce a lot of urine. **To conclude, we don't know for sure** if Latin urina and other IE words meaning water are cognates (originate from the same root).

Comment: Simpson = filius Symeonis

Comment: I don't think "drasticum mutamentum" is good Latin, it sounds like Italian with a Latin swing on it

Comment: @rearThing it's entirely possible that I macaronicked my way into that :). Mutamentum doesn't show up on Wiktionary, but drastikos is Greek, so maybe drastica mutatio? Then again, clickavi isn't much less macaronic :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Urina* is actually a euphemism, although how old is that euphemism is up for debate. The root of *urina* is a variant of the Proto-Indo-European *we-r-*, which [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=urine&allowed_in_frame=0) summarizes nicely:

> **ur-* variant of root *we-r- "water, liquid, milk" (cognates: Sanskrit var "water," Avestan var "rain," Lithuanian jures "sea," Old English wær, Old Norse ver "sea," Old Norse ur "drizzling rain")

So the original root had "wet" or "watery" connotations. *urinor* then would mean something akin to "to become wet", which is an apt description of diving.

Interestingly, the Greek *οὐρέω* (ouréō) and *οὖρον* (oũron) show the same euphemism, but lacks any meaning of "diving" in any of its forms.